# How to change data type in KDb+?

Tags: kdb, alter-table

I have created table as following in KDb+:

```
test:([doc_id:`symbol$()];doc_displayid:`symbol$();doc_created_date:`date$();doc_aacess_date:`timestamp$();is_native_exist:`boolean$();file_size:`real$())
```

Now I want to change the datatype of column `doc_id` from **`symbol`** to **`int`**.

How can I alter the test table and change **datatype**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the column to a string before you can convert it to an int:

```
q)update "I"$string doc_id from test
doc_id| doc_displayid doc_created_date doc_aacess_date is_native_exist file_s..
------| ---------------------------------------------------------------------..
```

You can verify the new type with `meta`:

```
q)meta update "I"$string doc_id from test
c               | t f a
----------------| -----
doc_id          | i
doc_displayid   | s
doc_created_date| d
doc_aacess_date | p
is_native_exist | b
file_size       | e
```

Comment: why do I need to convert it into the string?

Comment: I have check that not required to convert to the string before converting to integer.Thank You @thomas-smyth

Comment: If you try to cast directly from symbol to int you will find it throws and error (e.g. ``"I"$`123`456``). Casting to string is basically a middleman between both types.

Comment: Just as to why you have to convert it to a string:
Symbols in kdb are interned strings i.e a unique copy of all string values are stored in a global dictionary, and symbols are just references to that dictionary. As a result when you write
```"I"$`123```
what you are actually trying to convert is a reference (think of it like trying to change the label on a box, instead of what's in the box!)
when you write
```"I"$string `123```
you first get the value the reference points to then you cast that  (change what's in the box)
hopefully this helps